# What should I change in ogg header other then checksum when changing the segment table?

Tags: python, ogg, steganography, hex-editors

I tried to change an ogg page in the segment table, I recalculated the checksum and put it in the header, but the page seems to be discarded. What else should I change in order to make it work?